# Plotting points using Nested For Loops

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and we have been given this task to do:

> Write a C++ program which asks the user for a number n between 1 and 10.  The program should then print out n lines.  Each should consist of a number of stars of the same number as the current line number. For example:
>
> ```
> Please enter a number:   5
>
> *
> **
> ***
> ****
> *****
> ```

The problem I am having is that when I use the code I've written it displays wrong.

The code I have right now reads like this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 10:" << endl;
    cin >> n;


    for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= n; y++) {
            cout << "*" ;
        }
        cout << "*" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So for the example input of `5`, what is the *actual* output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is exactly as '@Lightness Races in Orbit' just explained to you. Let me add that if the requirement is just print out what you showed us, then no need for the last '*' nor the 'cin.get()':

```
for (int x = 0; x <= n; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < x; ++y) {
        cout << "*" ;
    }
    // No need for all the rest just print 'new line'
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Try it live!](http://ideone.com/zWcuKq)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Step through the logic of your program using pen and paper.

For your "horizontal" loop, you go all the way up to `n` each time. Is that right? I think you meant to go only as far as `x`, as this is the value that increases with each line.

The other problem is that you have one too many of everything, because you used `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: The output I get should have a single * on the first vertical line, then 2 on the next and so on until it reaches the entered number

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a nested loop.
This program works as well with one for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = n; i < 11; ++i) {
        cout << i << " " << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh forgot to say that we need to use a nested loop. This is like a practice assignment on how to use different types of loops.